# Android In-App Purchase User Identification

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am adding in-app purchase to my app. What details do I have to send to billing service in order to do the purchase process. I mean do we need to send any user mail id (market id) or something? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only sends product id but BillingService sends some information internally to the Android Market which includes the package name of your app. This package name is enough to identify your app. See the source code of BillingService at the following link (particularly line no 164);

http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/browse/src/com/example/dungeons/BillingService.java

Answer (score 2):

No you don't have to anything `In-App Billing` process automatically connects the app. All you need to send to is `productId` of the item to be purchased and that product should already exist on your app page. More info can be found on http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html

Comment: But how does the billing service identify each user without any of their identification like market account details ?

Comment: Which user are you talking about the customer or the seller?

Answer (score 2):

Users are identified by the Google account they used to sign in to the Android Market app. Managed products they buy are tied to this account, so that they can be restored even if the user resets their phone (or uses the same account on another device). It is send automatically by the Android Market when you call the billing APIs. You don't have to do anything special, it just works (when it's not broken).